# Bad behavior of floating-labels when autocomplete

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, floating-labels

I've using the [Floating labels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/floating-labels/) example from [Bootstrap 4.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3).

If the browser has already credentials on the autocompletement, the layout of `<input>` will breaks.

The animation (and the size & margin properties) of floating labels will only start, if the window/document has an focus.

How i can prevent these problem?

I've found the `CSS` propertie `:-webkit-autofill`, or try to focus the first `input` field, but the problem will be not solved.

**Preview:**

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the answer.

By default, the label will be styled only if the `placeholder` is not visible:

```css
.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
    padding-top: .25rem;
    padding-bottom: .25rem;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #777;
}
```

The trick is, to set the same `properties` if the `autofill` is presented with `:-webkit-autofill`:

```css
.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label,
.form-label-group input:-webkit-autofill ~ label /* <<<< Add these */
{
    padding-top: .25rem;
    padding-bottom: .25rem;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #777;
}
```

Comment: Btw. `:placeholder-shown` only works if there is a placeholder, so sometimes you need to provide `placeholder=" "`, even if you don't want to show a placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

i ended up having to split the recommendation above into 2 separate css rules in order to get CHROME and FIREFOX to place nice

```
.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
        padding-top: .25rem;
        padding-bottom: .25rem;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #777;
    }

.form-label-group input:-webkit-autofill ~ label {
    padding-top: .25rem;
    padding-bottom: .25rem;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #777;
}
```